# How to access a file programmatically in another Azure DevOps repository?

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops, oauth-2.0, oauth

I am trying to write a program to read an XML file residing in another git repository that is expected to change from to time.

I found this article at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#gititem that seems to point me to the right direction, but I am not entire sure how does the authentication work. I have never done anything with OAuth2 and if anyone has solved any similar problem, I would love to know how you solved them.

Thank in advance!

Comment: What is the context for needing this file? In a continuous delivery pipeline? As part of an application?

Comment: As part of a larger application.

Comment: Why does the file need to be retrieved directly from source control? Why can it not be included as part of the application during deployment?

Comment: Good question.  The file belongs to another team's repository.  I can't just include it in mine.  They stored a large amount of information in XML that way... It should be a database where we all have access, but this is the hand I was dealt and must deal with it.

Comment: If you have access to retrieve the file via the REST API, you have the access necessary to clone the repo in your pipeline and retrieve the file at build or deployment time.